# I have my by-days

Tags: word-meaning

From Stevenson's Virginibus Puerisque:

> I think it improbable that I shall ever write like Shakespeare,
>   conduct an army like Hannibal, or distinguish myself like Marcus
>   Aurelius in the paths of virtue; and yet I have my **by-days**, hope
>   prompting, when I am very ready to believe that I shall combine all
>   these various excellences in my own person, and go marching down to
>   posterity with divine honours.

Is *by-days* a word-play on *byways* here? Days when one's thoughts stray on a byway path from their usual run?

Comment: [See this link](http://wordincontext.com/en/by-days).  My guess is that this terminology has gone out of use, but that it probably meant something like a day away from the typical grind.

Comment: I, as a native speaker, have no idea.  But someone better educated might recognize it :-)  (I'm leaving this comment because I think there might be value in showing which expressions are *not* recognized by at least one native speaker.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find more of the quotation [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=B4MwAQAAMAAJ&dq=%22bydays%22&pg=PA25#v=onepage&q=%22bydays%22&f=false), and other examples [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=nOAoAAAAYAAJ&dq=%22bydays%22&pg=PA69#v=onepage&q=%22bydays%22&f=false), [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=uAcoAAAAYAAJ&dq=%22bydays%22&pg=PA75#v=onepage&q=%22bydays%22&f=false), and [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=45otAAAAMAAJ&q=%22bydays%22&dq=%22bydays%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ucCUUvO5GcP02gWG3YG4Ag&ved=0CNUCEOgBMDI).

The OED provides the following:

> Upon those **by-dayes** [i.e. days when there is no sermon] to runne to other Churches.
> <sub>— *William Laud · A speech delivered in the Starr-chamber · 1637*</sub>

> Being park-hack in the summer, and cover-hack in the winter, with a **bye-day** now and then when the country's light.
> <sub>— *Guy Livingstone · 1857*</sub>

The OED also lists the phrase **“day on which an activity does not take place”** as a synonym.

Nowadays, we’d just call it a [day off](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+%22day+off%22).

This form of “by(e)-” survives in sports jargon as [“bye week”](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+%22bye+week%22), or even [“bye”](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bye_%28sports%29)—which can mean a day off.

---

With regards to your quotation from *Virginibus Puerisque*, the best explanation I can manage is that Stevenson generally (most days) has realistically low expectations for his legacy, but on some days hope wells up in him, he vacations from pessimism, and he believes that he will achieve greatness. ([He did](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Louis_Stevenson).)